# Chrome extension XHR to localhost never arrives?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to write a chrome extension, and this is the first time I have needed to POST to a server with one. If I fire a request in Postman to my local server at `https://localhost:80/savelink` I get a 200 and the server behaves accordingly. However, when I try to fire a request from the chrome extension, the server behavior is never triggered. The request is as follows (only slightly modified from the example):

```
chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
        var tab = tabs[0];

        var url = tab.url;


        console.assert(typeof url == 'string', 'tab.url should be a string');
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open("POST", 'https://localhost:80/savelink', true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        request.send({ tab_url: url });
        console.log("HIT");
    });
```

My manifest.json permissions look like this (can you tell I am pulling my hair?):

```
"permissions": [
"activeTab",
    "https://localhost/*",
    "https://*/",
    "http://*/"
  ]
```

and relevant parts of my server look like:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.post('/savelink', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);  // this log is never triggered when the route is hit through chrome
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

I am running Chrome Canary with the --disable-web-security flag set.  I am still getting an insecure response on the client side, but I think that is probably irrelevant.

Comment: I've looked at many similar questions and not been able to find a solution :(

Comment: Did you try to look what the XMLHttpRequest is saying with the error?

Comment: Do you see the outgoing request in devtools network panel of the extension page? Just in case: both the popup and the background page have their own devtools, not the one that's displayed for web pages.

Comment: @epascarello The error just says that it's an insecure response, because I can't seem to get it to *actually* disable security

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes, I am looking at the popup devtools, I don't believe I have a background page set up.

Comment: Probably because of a self sign cert.... I think the flag is `--ignore-certificate-errors`

Comment: Doesn't fix the insecure response error.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out, thank you to the commenters, you were all pretty much on the right path.  I did have to run `open -a "Google Chrome Canary" --args --user-data-dir --disable-web-security`, but on top of that, any change made to the server relaunches it (which I blanked on).  That means that in order to get my calls to work, I need to navigate to a route on my server, load it, accept the warning, and *then* open my extension and send my `POST`.  Change the extension means I have to do that + reload the extension.  Sorry to everyone I responded to, y'all were right, I missed some steps.